React native: Installing a template: An unexpected error occurred: Command failed with EACCES
I have tried with all ways to install a custom template:

NPM package
github url
local directory

and I am stuck in this error:
✔ Downloading template
✔ Copying template
✔ Processing template
ℹ Executing post init script 


error An unexpected error occurred: Command failed with EACCES: /var/folders/59/jzkbfx8x3mqd8xnxjgnq0nqw0000gn/T/rncli-init-template-eUHHLa/node_modules/react-native-template/script.js
spawn /var/folders/59/jzkbfx8x3mqd8xnxjgnq0nqw0000gn/T/rncli-init-template-eUHHLa/node_modules/react-native-template/script.js EACCES.

You can just follow normal way to create a custom template as:
https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/docs/init.md#initializing-project-with-custom-template
I have tried something with chmod but not really works in my cases.

I have found a way to hack the problem to use this template and it was to deleting postInintScript in package.json. But not solve the real problem. I would like to know how to run script.js
